# typedef in template c++ class doen't work when define out side of class?

Tags: c++

I also tried to use typedef in my template c++, but it does't work, and i don't know how to fix it.

```
template <typename object>
class MyVector
{
public:
    typedef object* iter;
    iter begin();
};

template <typename object>
iter MyVector<object>::begin() //here is problem
{

}
```

can you tell me why it doesn't work?

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`iter` doesn't mean anything in that context, you need to explicitly qualify it:

```
template <typename object>
typename MyVector<object>::iter MyVector<object>::begin()
{

}
```

In C++11 you can use a trailing return type:

```
template <typename object>
auto MyVector<object>::begin() -> iter
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the compiler has no idea that it must search for `iter` inside `MyVector<object>` when it encounters the token `iter`.  Explicitly provide a scope for `iter` like so:

```
template <typename object>
typename MyVector<object>::iter MyVector<object>::begin() //here is problem
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
template <typename object>
class MyVector
{
public:
    typedef object* iter;
    iter begin();
};

template <typename object>
typename MyVector<object>::iter MyVector<object>::begin() //here is problem
{

}
```

Typename `iter` is a member of class `MyVector` and you have to use the syntax for accessing class members.

Answer (score 0):

`iter` it's like inner type in you sample you need specify main class type before it for any usage outside the main class:

```
MyVector<object>::iter
```

Comment: You also need `typename` because it's a dependent name.